# How to show a windows form as a Dialog into VSTO word addin?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, vsto

I have a VSTO Project (WinWord addin) using c#.

The Project has only one window, it must be showed when click on some button, the problem is that it only happens when i'm debuging, if i try to use it after run the installation, it doesn't show the window. Here is my ribbon code:

```
public partial class MyRibbon
{
    private void MyRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnPublicar_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        MyForm form = new MyForm();
        //form.TopLevel = true; 
        form.ShowDialog();
        //form.Show();
    }

    private void gallery1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void editBox1_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

The commented code are some tries. Any help tks.

Answer (score 2):

After very deep debug, found my addin were throwing an non handeled exception (some XML files needed by addin are lost. They weren't where they should), the extrange thing is that Word doesn't show the problem, simply doesn´t open the form.